# creating 5 bash operators in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I have the following airflow code:

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='example_python_operator', default_args=args,
    schedule_interval=None)
for i in range(5):
    t = BashOperator(
        task_id = 'some_id',
        params={'i':i},
        bash_command = "python airflow/scripts/a.py '{{ execution_date }}' '{{ params.i }}' '{{ prev_execution_date }}'" ,
        dag = dag)
    set_upstream(t)
```

However this doesn't work... Apparently I cant do `set_upstream(t)`.
Basically I want to run the script 5 times with these parameters:

```
python airflow/scripts/a.py    '{{ execution_date }}' 0 '{{ prev_execution_date }}'
python airflow/scripts/a.py    '{{ execution_date }}' 1 '{{ prev_execution_date }}'
python airflow/scripts/a.py    '{{ execution_date }}' 2 '{{ prev_execution_date }}'
python airflow/scripts/a.py    '{{ execution_date }}' 3 '{{ prev_execution_date }}'
python airflow/scripts/a.py    '{{ execution_date }}' 4 '{{ prev_execution_date }}'
```

Each run is totally separate than the other so they can run simultaneously.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use airflow's DummyOperator (an operator that does nothing) as a start task and set the upstream to that. Like this:

```
from airflow.operators import DummyOperator
...

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='example_dag', default_args=args,
    schedule_interval=None)

start_task = DummyOperator(task_id='start_task', dag=dag)

for i in range(5):
    t = BashOperator(
        task_id = 'task_{0}'.format(i),
        params={'i':i},
        bash_command = "python airflow/scripts/a.py '{{ execution_date }}' '{{ params.i }}' '{{ prev_execution_date }}'" ,
        dag = dag)

    t.set_upstream(start_task)
```

Comment: name 'set_upstream' is not defined

Comment: @jack I just copy / pasted your code substituting in the DummyOperator bit. I edited the post to fix it - it should be `t.set_upstream(start_task)`

Comment: @jack So: Problem 1) you called a method of a class without using dot notation. Problem 2) which task of the 5 did you want up stream? It seems you like Simon's suggestion to make a dummy task be the upstream.
Just be aware you get extra scheduling lag that way. Which is normally just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code would make 5 tasks and they'd run approximately in parallel if you just remove the `set_upstream(t)`.

If you had `t1` and `t2` you could do `t2.set_upstream(t1)`, or `t1 >> t2`, but since you *want them to run simultaneously* you best not set it.

You will have to give each task a unique `task_id` though.

```
tasks = []
with DAG(
        dag_id='example_python_operator',
        default_args=args,
        schedule_interval=None
    ) as dag:
        tasks = [ BashOperator(
                      task_id = 'some_id_{}'.format(i),
                      params={'i':i},
                      bash_command="""python airflow/scripts/a.py \
                                   '{{ execution_date }}'\
                                   '{{ params.i }}'\
                                   '{{ prev_execution_date }}'""",
                  ) for i in range(5) ]
```

Comment: But if I don't do set_upstream then how would the task get execute?

Comment: Well, once the DAG starts it does a topological sort and then goes from the tasks whose dependencies (these have none) are met.